# Fitting kernel density estimation across columns in a python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, kernel

I am trying to apply a kde across all the columns of a dataframe (df)- where each column is a time series. At the moment i am just trying to apply it to one column and it's not working, and i don't know why!

here's the code:

```
kde=KernelDensity (bandwidth=0.5,kernel='gaussian')
kde.fit(df[df.columns[1]])
```

and the error message is this:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
```

sorry it's probably really obvious, just i don't know how to fix it!

Comment: `df.iloc[:,[1]]`

Comment: thank you, really helpful - that worked! :)